# How to store and access encryption keys across Flutter apps

Tags: flutter, firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a suite of two different Flutter apps that share a single firestore database.

The first app generates a QR code that would then be scanned and verified by a user of the second app. The QR code information is a string that contains some information I don't want users to see by simply scanning the QR code with their camera app.

I want to encrypt the string in the first app before encoding it into a QR code, and decrypt the string in the second app after the QR code has been scanned, but that means I would need to have the encryption key accessible in both apps.

Would I have to hardcode this key into the apps or transmit the key through the database?  How can I achieve this in the most secure way possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use almost any mechanism you want to transmit the keys, but the one thing you shouldn't do is transmit it through the same database as where you store the encrypted data - as that would put that data at risk if the database is compromised.

So mail them, text them, write them on a piece of paper and mail it, or you can organize an in-person meeting/party where you exchange them (h/t to Little Brother). It doesn't really matter how, as long as it's a different mechanism than you used to store/exchange the actual data that is encrypted with those keys.

You *can* hard-code them in the apps too, but what the keeps anyone from downloading that app too and using it? Or is that precisely what you want, in which case